# Does any RigVedic God besides Indra fight the enemies of the Aryas - like Dasas,Dasyus et al?

Tags: rig-veda, indra, arya

Some citations from Rig Veda

> 1 100
> 18 He, much invoked, hath slain Dasyus and Śimyus, after his wont, and laid them low with arrows.
> The mighty Thunderer with his **fair-complexioned** friends won the land, the sunlight, and the waters.

> 9 73
> 5 O'er Sire and Mother they have roared in unison bright with the verse of praise, burning up riteless men,
> Blowing away with supernatural might from earth and from the heavens the **swarthy skin which Indra hates.**

Vishnu assists him in the fight with Vrtra - but Vrtra is a metaphor and not a non-Arya human enemy.

Is Indra the supreme warrior leader of the Rigvedic Aryas?

Comment: Indra is the god of war so I am guessing he will be the only one who defends.

Comment: Kinda like that, Indra is god of many features in R̥g Veda, but war and rain are his unique abilities. There are many more hymns actually which discuss his war time exploits and his victories.

Answer (score 0):

Rig Veda Mandala 1 , Hymn 19 couplet 5

5. They who are brilliant, of terrible designs, powerful, and devourers of foes; with the Maruts come hither, O Agni!

In Vedic it is मरुद्भिर्ग्न Maruts with Agni as  in a translation O Agni with the Maruts come.